# How should I build an angularjs page with direct link that impact the page content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location-provider

I have a 'Google search' like page, that presenting a list of items that the back-end returned.

In the page there is an HTML form with many different fields. The user is able to change one or many of the values in those fields and then the back-end will return new relevant list of items.

One of the requests is to give the user the ability to open a direct link of filtered results, this is done until now with query params in the url, but now I want to change this page to work asynchronously with angularjs. There is an assumption that the fields in that filter form can be changed from time to time.

So after all that, what is the best way to handle in angularjs with complex forms like that and allow get method of the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thoughts, I've got a solution.

Some of the 'magic' here is to have one object in the $scope (named $scope.filter) to hold all the form input values, so it is easy to work with, and do not require any modification to that part in the controller if a new input is added to the form.

```
    angular.module('myApp')

    .controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http' '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.filter = {};

        $scope.init = function(){
            // $location.search() will return an object with the params,
            // those values are set to $scope.filter, and the filter values are initialized in case of direct link to the page
            $scope.filter = $location.search();

            $scope.executeFilter();
        };

        // doing the job of fetching the data I want to present,
        // using the filter values as a Json in that server call
        $scope.executeFilter = function(){
            // making sure to update the url with the current filter values,
            // so the user is able to copy the relevant url for a later use
            $location.search($scope.filter);

            var paramsAsJson = angular.toJson($location.search());

            $http.post('my-url', paramsAsJson).success(function(data) {
                // update view
            });
        };

        $scope.init();


    }]);
```

And this is an example view:

```
<form ng-submit="executeFilter()">
    <input name="some_text" type="text" ng-model="filter.some_text">
    <!-- more inputs here -->

    // it will work even with multiple select
    // (will pass to the server a json with array of selected values)
    <select multiple="multiple" name="some_options" ng-model="filter.some_options">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>   
    <button>Filter</button>
</form>
```

So now if a user is trying to open this page with url like this `www.my-url.com/?some_text=foo` the input with the directive `ng-model="filter.some_text"` will contain 'foo' after page is loaded, and a server request with that param will be made.

Answer (score 0):

You can always build a URL in your scope in response to whatever the user is up to and then do something like `<a ng-attr-href="{{view.userURL}}" target="_blank">{{view.userURL}}</a>`